# issue with multiple inheritance in Java

Tags: java, oop

I would like to model the following classes in Java:

[image]

so I came with the following code:

```
class Person
{
    private String name;
    private ing age;
    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
    //set and get methods
}

class Employee
{
    private String nameEmp;
    private double salary;
    public Employee(String nameEmp, double salary){
        this.nameEmp=nameEmp;
        this.salary=salary;
    }
    public double calcSalary(){}   //should this be an abstract method?
}

class Teacher extends Person implements Employee
{
    private String nameTeacher;
    private int ageTeacher;
    private String title;   //professor or lecturer
    public Teacher(String nameTeacher,int ageTeacher, String title){
        super(nameTeacher,ageTeacher);
        this.title=title;
    }
    public double calcSalary(){
        if (title.equals("Professor")) salary=salary*0,30;
        else if (title.equals("Lecturer")) salary=salary*0,10;
    }
}
```

I would like to model it using interfaces, but I am not quite sure how to do it. Also the calcSalary should be an abstract method in Employee? How this can be implemented with interfaces in Java?

Thanks

Comment: You could say `class Teacher implements Person, Employee`

Comment: thanks @TheCat, but please could you correct my code? I know that the interfaces should be empty, but Employee has got a method and atributes already, can I not model this with interfaces?

Comment: I think your example is a bit confusing. A better one might be: `Teacher` is an `Employee` which is a `Person`.

Comment: you can use an abstract class

Comment: So no one as told him yet that one cannot implement a class?

Comment: is an employee not a person?

Comment: good comment @eis, but I have found this example and I got the doubt how to do it in Java

Comment: Is Teacher a Person, or is Teacher the role a person has in a certain context, or is Teacher the role description of an Employee etc?

Comment: @jma you can write FORTRAN in Java, but it's not a good idea. When working in a language you should use that language's modeling paradigm.  Java doesn't have multiple inheritance, so let go of that perspective.  That leaves you with multiple layers of single inheritance or interfaces, both of which others have suggested to you.  If you want implementations of the methods, you need the former, because as of now interfaces don't do implementations.

Comment: Java `float`s and `double`s always use decimal points to separate the integral part from the fractional part. `salary=salary*0,30` should be `salary=salary*0.30`; you'll be grately surprised when you end up with `salary` being set to `30` otherwise, as you will be invoking the *comma operator*.

Comment: An entirely different approach might be to create a Job class, with Teacher being either a subclass or a parameterization of Job.  Then implement that a Person _has a_ Job, i.e., job is an instance variable for each Person.  Reflect queries about a Person's salary, title, etc, to their Job object.  This could be extended to track Career - each person's Career would be a series of Jobs.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do it this way, you should go for Teacher is -> Employee is -> Person. You can't implement anything in interface! Interface can only contain methods that should be implemented by class.

Answer (score 3):

You could have this:

```
public interface Person{
    // Only abstract methods here
}

public interface Employee extends Person {
    // Only abstract methods here specific to Employee
}

public class Teacher implements Employee {
    //Implements the methods 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 will allow you to place default implementations in interfaces. Until then, interfaces cannot contain implementations.

Comment: I don't understand how could you implement getters and setters in an interface though.

Comment: I think your real question is "How do I do multiple inheritance in Java?" and the answer is, you don't.

Comment: No, that's not my question. I just wonder that even knowing that Java 8 supports giving default implementations for the methods, how would you make default implementation for getters and setters to solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, I support Balázs Mária Németh's comment. A `Teacher` should extend from `Employee` that should extend from `Person`.

Comment: I think you're successfully arguing that adding default implementations to Java is a terrible idea. ;) To answer seriously, though, an interface does not have properties (or any state) so you would not expect to have default implementations of getters or setters. You might, on the other hand, have a default implementation of calcSalary() that calls other methods (such as getters) defined on the interface.

Comment: Again, I'm not arguing nor ranting about interfaces having default implementation for methods. I'm just asking how this would solve OP's current design problem.

Comment: "Also the calcSalary should be an abstract method in Employee? How this can be implemented with interfaces in Java?" Is that not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Start with Person.  You had a typo there:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
    // set and get methods, equals, hashCode, toString,
    // perhaps an id for database storage.
}
```

Now, some `Person`s are `Employee`s; others are students, parents, prospective students, and so on.  If any method of `Employee` has an implementation, it can't be an interface.  And in any case, having `nameEmp` is wrong since it will duplicate the name in `Person`.  Either you create an interface for Employee that gets mixed into the `Teacher` class, or you inherit from `Employee`.

Either:

```
public interface Employee {
    // Currency values should use BigDecimal or BigInteger, not double.
    BigDecimal salary();
    // Taxpayer Identification Number (SSN) in the USA, or the equivalent outside.
    String taxNumber();
}
```

or:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    private BigDecimal salary;
    private String taxNumber;
    public Employee(String name, int age, BigDecimal salary,
                    String taxNumber) {
        super(name, age);
        this.salary = salary;
        this.taxNumber = taxNumber;
        this.title = title;
    }
    // getters, setters, etc.
}

public class Teacher extends Employee {
    private Department department;
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

You should only have the salary methods in Teacher if they need a wildly-different implementation.  You might want to have some sort of pay calaculator class (the Strategy pattern) in the Employee class instead.  This way you can handle taxable deductions, insurance, pension plans, overtime where applicable.  I didn't understand the multipliers in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    int getAge();
    void setAge(int age);
}

public class PersonImpl implements Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @override public String getName() { return this.name; }
    @override public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    @override public int getAge() { return this.age; }
    @override public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}

public interface Employee extends Person {
    double getSalary();
    void setSalary(double salary);
    double calcSalary();
}

public abstract class EmployeeImpl extends PersonImpl implements Employee {
    private double salary;
    @override public double getSalary() { return this.salary; }
    @override public void setSalary(double salary) { this.salary = salary; }
}

public class Teacher extends EmployeeImpl
    @override public double calcSalary() { 
        if (title.equals("Professor")) salary=salary*0,30;
        else if (title.equals("Lecturer")) salary=salary*0,10;
    }
}
```